# Installing python software in virtual environment gives 'Permission denied' error

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv, permission-denied

I am trying to install a piece of python software on our server(http://integronfinder.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5/). However, I am not the server administrator and cannot run the command under `sudo`, as I get a 'permission denied' error when I try it. I tried circumventing the problem through creating a virtual environment and installing the program there, but I still get the same error!

```
(my_root) [user1@server Integron_Finder-1.5]$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_scripts
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/integron_finder from 664 to 775
running install_scripts
moving build/scripts-2.7/integron_finder.tmp -> build/scripts-2.7/integron_finder
copying build/scripts-2.7/integron_finder -> /home/user1/.conda/envs/my_root/bin
changing mode of /home/user1/.conda/envs/my_root/bin/integron_finder to 775
running install_data
creating /usr/share/integron_finder
error: could not create '/usr/share/integron_finder': Permission denied
```

Installing the software in a virtual environment is also what the developers suggest for users that do not have administrator rights. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I could try to fix it?

Comment: you should post this as an issue: https://github.com/gem-pasteur/Integron_Finder/issues, the dev will discuss with you directly

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual env is a good idea and it should work even if you have no admin rights.

I am one of the Integron_finder package dev. You should submit an issue on the [github page](http://github.com/gem-pasteur/Integron_Finder/issues) of the project with all details.
I will check quickly what goes wrong in the installation with a virtualenv.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply! Problem is already solved though, our admin installed the software for me!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that much you can do than to try to get sudo permission in some way or another.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Can you explain to me what the problem here is? I guess that the installation script tries to put some stuff into directories that are 'root regulated', but I thought that that problem should be solved through just copying all those directories through creating a virtual environment? Sorry if the question is basic, I am quite new to all this.